# Questions regarding angle of incline of truncated cones

Tags: trigonometry

My question is a little more complicated than what the title says. I am trying to take a truncated cone and form an accurate 2D net drawing of it so it can be cut out and folded into the same 3D truncated cone. I am following this guide here: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/carlcone/solutionpaula.html

My questions are:

1. How can I find the angle of incline of side "b"?
2. How would I take the final 2D net drawing of this truncated cone and solve for this angle of incline of line b, if the 3D representation of it were not presented?

Answer (score 0):

1. The angle of incline (base angle) is
   $$
   \arccos{(0.125/a)} = \arctan{(h/0.125)}$$
2. Extend the edges until they meet and measure distance $a+b$ from this point (O) to one of the base corners. The base radius $(R)$ is the length of the base arc $(L)$  divided by $2\pi$. To obtain the arc length measure the angle ($\theta$, radians) subtended at point O and calculate 
   $$
   L = (a+b)\theta. 
   $$
   If working in degrees
   $$
   \theta(radians) = \theta(degrees)\pi/180
   $$